# Formula causes #REF! error in one cell, but not another

Tags: indexing, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My formula

```
=INDEX(taskCategories!$C$1:$J$1,MAX(IF(taskCategories!$C$2:$J=C2,COLUMN(taskCategories!$C$2:$J)-COLUMN(C2)-1)))`
```

works fine in one column, but if there is data to the right, I get an `#REF!` error.  I assume the formula is attempting to write blank data from the selected range, but I'm not savvy enough to know how to eliminate those blank values in the formula.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[My sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Za3a9d3hKJCMAxy72sIRH9L61wLwvBw02Fwj_9E_z-4/edit#gid=1609799406&range=B2) subTaskData!B2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap it into another `INDEX` like:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(taskCategories!$C$1:$J$1,
 MAX(IF(taskCategories!$C$2:$J=C6,COLUMN(taskCategories!$C$2:$J)-COLUMN(C6)-1))),1,1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Yes but this doesn't answer the question of why Index should be trying to create a range of more than one cell in the first place. I'm pretty sure it's because the MAX function actually returns zero so you get the whole range C1:J1.